# Use VSCode get pointer point to what type of object?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am using VSCode to debug C++ project with CMake:Debug extension.

But I find the debugger can't know what type the pointer point to.

How to solve this?  For example, see the program in below picture. I want debugger show s1 point to **Rectangle** object, and the s2 point to **Square** object.
[image]